# How to find the correspond value in a column due to a max value from another column group by other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Due a dataframe like:

| COUNTRY_CODE | PDP_SOURCE | TREAT_SLIT | ATC_METRIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AR | Aisles | ex_1 | 12.78 |
| AR | Aisles | ex_2 | 11.28 |
| AR | Aisles | ex_3 | 11.96 |
| AR | Favorites | ex_1 | 12.78 |
| AR | Favorites | ex_2 | 12.28 |
| AR | Favorites | ex_3 | 13.96 |
| BR | Favorites | ex_1 | 11.2 |
| BR | Favorites | ex_2 | 10.28 |
| BR | Favorites | ex_3 | 10.96 |

I need to groupby this by COUNTRY_CODE,PDP_SOURCE and find the TREATMENT_SPLIT which has the max ATC_METRIC value. Is there a way to do this with .groupby in pandas? the result should be something like:

| COUNTRY_CODE | PDP_SOURCE | TREAT_SLIT | ATC_METRIC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AR | Aisles | ex_1 | 12.78 |
| AR | Favorites | ex_3 | 13.96 |
| BR | Favorites | ex_1 | 11.2 |

Comment: You can aggregate the groupby using idxmax, which will give you the index labels of the maximum atc_metric. You can use those labels to retrieve your required output from the original data.

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# use groupby to get the index where ATC_METRIC is max, then 
# use loc to return those rows

df.loc[df.groupby(['COUNTRY_CODE','PDP_SOURCE'] )['ATC_METRIC'] .idxmax()]
```

Result

```
    COUNTRY_CODE    PDP_SOURCE  TREAT_SLIT  ATC_METRIC
0             AR    Aisles            ex_1  12.78
5             AR    Favorites         ex_3  13.96
6             BR    Favorites         ex_1  11.20
```

Comment: Data is already in text

Comment: @JuanJoseVargasEstevez, added result of the solution. Does it work for you?